# Getting /script.sh: not found in Jenkins during running the docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My goal is to run a copyright job on Jenkins Declarative Pipeline.

When I run an image locally using these commands it works fine:

```
docker pull avidregistry.azurecr.io/my_repo/gocopyright:latest
docker run -v $(pwd):/workspace avidregistry.azurecr.io/my_repo/gocopyright:latest gocopyright -g
```

But when I added a copyright stage to Jenkinsfile and running the same image:

```
        stage('Copyright') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'avidregistry.azurecr.io/my_repo/gocopyright:latest'
                    args '-v $PWD:/workspace'
                    reuseNode true
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'gocopyright -g'
                sh 'ls -la'
                sh 'pwd'
            }
        }
```

I get an exception like this one:

```
[my-pipeline@2] Running shell script
sh: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-pipeline@2@tmp/durable-d3f6e37a/script.sh: not found
```

What`s the problem in? How can I fix it?

Comment: Debug it with find. Add a step `sh 'find . -name \*.sh -print'` and run the pipeline to see if `script.sh` is there. In general, you should figure out how to run the scripts/commands in the container _interactively_, then duplicate those commands in your groovy code in the pipeline.

Comment: I have the same issue. Seems to be Jenkins related. I have no Docker. Nothing called like `durable` or `script.sh` exists in my project....

Comment: I think that it might be related to an error in some of the `sh` commands, maybe the `gocopyright -g` in your case?

Comment: What is the base docker image you are using for your custom image and does it have a shell? Because the command that Jenkins would be executing would look something like `docker run -v $PWD:/workspace avidregistry.azurecr.io/my_repo/gocopyright:latest sh -c "gocopyright -g"`